# War file is missing Web.xml and Weblogic.xml

Tags: maven, spring-boot, weblogic, war, web.xml

I have a Spring boot project which is being deployed to Weblogic. However, the WAR file that is being generated by Maven, is not including the Weblogic.xml and Web.xml and I do not know why.

Can anybody tell me if there is something I am missing? Below is my pom.xml for the project.

There is a shared library deployed on the Weblogic server which is where the dependencies are pulled from.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.cds.app</groupId>
<artifactId>webapp</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>cds-webapp-war</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <spring.boot.version>2.0.0.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
    <bambooBuildNumber>999999</bambooBuildNumber>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency> 

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
      <artifactId>weblogic-server-pom</artifactId>
      <version>12.2.1-0-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>webapp-cds-${project.version}.${bambooBuildNumber}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <packagingExcludes>
                    WEB-INF/lib/logback*.jar,
                    WEB-INF/lib/*tomcat*.jar
                </packagingExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had just the problem prior this week. It was very silly mistake. One project was building war file with both "web.xml" & "weblogic.xml" in it and another one didn't. Both were build with gradle. In my case the one didn't include them(web+weblogic).xml because I mistakenly wrote "web-app", which contained META-INF & WEB-INF. On the other hand, the project which build the war properly had "webapp". So it was able to detect "web.xml" & "webapp.xml" properly. In your case kindly try to find similar problem with naming or something that prevented from detecting those files.